# Открывать окно с конкретной инфой

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api, firebase

Есть фрагмент, содержащий карту.

В ней у меня есть маркеры, где я определяю клик по тому или иному маркеру, благодаря его заголовку следующим способом:

```
googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker marker) {
        if(marker.getTitle().equals("Orange"))
        bottom_sheet_frame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        return false;
    }
});
```

После чего у меня открывается `bottom_sheet_frame` со статичными данными.

Также у меня есть модель, с некоторыми полями, которые будут располагаться в моём bottom_sheet_frame (чтобы не захламлять код не буду выкладывать всю модель с конструктором и геттерами/сеттерами):

```
public class Info {
    public String title;
    public String subTitle;
    public String address;
    public String phoneNumber;
}
```

Вопрос наверное можно разделить на две части:

1. Как правильно хранить информацию для **bottom_sheet**'a в бд Firebase?
   Полностью фрагмент можно посмотреть [здесь](https://gist.github.com/mnewlive/123fcc4fe06cb25c1336ec7a57be388c). *Здесь реализовано хранение информации для самого маркера*.
2. Как по нажатию на тот или иной маркер пушить конкретную информацию для этого маркера.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/infowindows?hl=ru

Comment: В чем конкретная проблема? Не открывается bottom sheet или вы не знаете как передать в него данные? Код для bottom sheet тоже добавьте?

Comment: @eugeneek обновил вопрос, вроде все аспекты осветил. Проблема заключается в том, чтоб передавать в bottom sheet данные которые храню в db firebase

Comment: Добавьте ещё xml layout. Раз данные хранятся в бд, то передавать их не надо. Передавайте id записи, а потом вытаскивайте данные по этому id, там, где они нужны.

Comment: @eugeneek они ещё не хранятся, в прикрепленном коде сохранял данные для маркера только. Сейчас примерно также пробую сохранять данные для bottom_sheet'a, но пока не оч получается. Тоже пробую создать класс и запушить егов firebase, после чего просто получать по полям данные для того или инного объекта. В ссылке с кодом добавил layout'ы

Comment: @eugeneek если  правильно понял из кода, у автора данные маркера уже хранятся в бд, он хочет эти же данные использовать для bottom_sheet'a?

Comment: @Morozov я, честно говоря, так и не смог понять, в чем именно проблема.

Comment: @eugeneek по моему проблема в сохранении каких то данных(n) с последующим их отображением в его bottom_sheet'e.
Данные в бд вроде уже есть. Или это не совсем то? Вроде как создаётся объект , после чего он пушает в firebase и уже оттуда их получает, поправь если не туда думаю)
Если так, то остаётся только правильно выводить их в bottom_sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Наверное не совсем понял вопрос, но давайте разбираться вместе.
Вам необходимо сохранять данные маркера в Firebase.

У Вас есть модель в которой Вы используете те или иные поля для дальнейшего отображения. В бд Firease для получения из нее информации  используются listeners — в Вашем случае это объекты, которые устанавливаются на узел, подузел или поле данных и которые «слушают» какие-либо события на них, как например, добавление новой информации или изменение старой.

В коде я заметил что у вас подвязаны слушатели на детей: `onChildAdded()`.

Для того чтобы создать бд для Вам повторно нужно создать объект, допустим InfoTable, которую будете пушать как Вы уже делали для маркеров в бд Firebase.

И уже после чего получать информацию посредством модели из Вашей бд для bottom_sheet'a.